# Flash AS2 - Accessing a loadVariable variables with a number on the end of it

Tags: flash, variables, actionscript-2

I have a flash that loads variables from a mysql database. It loads them with their id appending the variable

Example:
 **Variable Name**:itemName
**Id**:1
**var sent to flash**:&itemName1=(item name in database)

Now the problem is in flash loading that variable with the added id at the end

**Code**:

```
onClipEvent(data){
    t = this.totalItems;
    for(i = 1;i <= t;i++){
        itemNames = this.itemName + i;
        _root.itemList.addItemAt(i, itemNames);
    }
}
```

But the list returns **NaN**. I so far have 2 items in my database so these are the values returned.

- itemName1
- description1
- price1
- itemName2
- description2
- price2

so I thought `this.itemName + i` would return the value **itemName1** where **i=1** in the for loop. Is there any other way to do this? Any ideas why this isn't working? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

p.s.  This is what the php file returns
`&totalItems=2&itemName1=Name Change&price1=150&desc1=Buying this will allow a name change.&itemName2=VIP Status&price2=2000&desc2=Allows to have the VIP Status which allow special features.`
I know it works because **t** does return 2 in the flash.

EDIT:
ok so I tried changing itemNames = this.itemName + "" + i and it just returns "undefined1", "undefined2" etc... this is becoming a headache. and loadvars just crashes my flash.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use the [LoadVars](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001174.html) class for loading external variables.  You can then use bracket syntax to access them by name:

```
var lvars:LoadVars = new LoadVars();
var i:int = 0;
// ...

var key:String = this.itemName + "" + i;
var value:String = lvars[key];
```

[This example](http://snipplr.com/view/8878/) should help you to get started with LoadVars.

Comment: ok loadvars is not working at all, in fact it crashes the flash on my webpage. Im just gonna stick with loadVariables

Comment: I doubt that LoadVars is at fault. But suit yourself.